# ASP.NET Toaster Notification immediately after Onclick Event Not working

Tags: asp.net

Question updated.

Reference:
http://www.startuppirates.org/blog/gritter/

Following is working fine, when click on the html link "Add Regular" it shows the notification so related .js and .css is working.

HTML Link

```
<a href="#" id="add-regular">Add regular notification</a>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#add-regular').click(function () {

        var unique_id = $.gritter.add({
            // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
            title: 'This is a regular notice!',
            // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
            text: 'This will fade out after a certain amount of time.',
            // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
            image: '/content/gritter/images/success.png',
            // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just sit there
            sticky: false,
            // (int | optional) the time you want it to be alive for before fading out
            time: '',
            class_name: 'gritter-info'
        });
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

I have modified above JS into a function with parameters, and I'm trying to call it to show the notification from code-behind (asp.net / web-forms) but it is not working !

Codebehind

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "return", "stickyalert('Property Upload', 'property data uploaded successfully', 0, 'success');", True)
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function stickyalert(title, text, sticky, success) {
        var unique_id = $.gritter.add({
            // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
            title: title,
            // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
            text: text,
            // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
            image: '/content/gritter/images/success.png',
            // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just sit there
            sticky: sticky,
            // (int | optional) the time you want it to be alive for before fading out
            time: '5000',
            // (string | optional) the class name you want to apply to that specific message
            class_name: 'gritter-info'
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Without code, no. I have no idea.

Comment: I'm using same code on : https://dotnetco.de/use-toast-notification-popups-in-asp-net/

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve minimal, complete, and verifiable example. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask good questions.